# Show simple products URL in bundle summary

Tags: php, javascript, magento2.4, bundled-product, bundle-product

We want to make product name clickable in bundle summary.

When user click on product it should be redirected to simple product page.

Anyone knows if it possible?

### [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible indeed, but you should know your way around UI components in Magento2 !

Bundle Summary is rendered by the UI component called from the template file `summary.phtml`

> vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/**summary.phtml**

```
<div class="bundle-summary">
        <strong class="subtitle"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Summary')) ?></strong>
        <div id="bundle-summary" data-container="product-summary">
            <ul data-mage-init='{"productSummary": []}' class="bundle items"></ul>
            <script data-template="bundle-summary" type="text/x-magento-template">
                <li>
                    <strong class="label"><%- data._label_ %>:</strong>
                    <div data-container="options"></div>
                </li>
            </script>
            <script data-template="bundle-option" type="text/x-magento-template">
                <div><?= /* @noEscape */ __('%1 x %2', '<%- data._quantity_ %>', '<%- data._label_ %>') ?></div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You have to modify the script at the end to this one

```
<script data-template="bundle-option" type="text/x-magento-template">
  <div><?= /* @noEscape */ __('%1 x <a href="%2" target="_blank">%3</a>', '<%- data._quantity_ %>', '<%- data._productUrl_ %>', '<%- data._label_ %>') ?></div>
</script>
```

Note that **`data._productUrl_`** has been added which contains the product URL. The Product URL is not available by default,

You have to add this to **`priceBundle.optionConfig`** Object before you use it in your template.

In order to do this, add this in the Block responsible to add the bundle product configurations

> Magento\Bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle.php

pluginize / override (preference) this class in your module and modify the method

`getJsonConfig`

Though the exact method that you need to modify is `getSelectionItemData` which is private so it cannot be overriden, so include that in your overriden class and add the `productUrl` to the array which returns the bundle product config as shown below.

> private function getSelectionItemData(Product $product, Product
> $selection)

```
return [
            'qty' => $qty,
            'customQty' => $selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty(),
            'optionId' => $selection->getId(),
            'prices' => [
                'oldPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $oldPrice,
                ],
                'basePrice' => [
                    'amount' => $basePrice,
                ],
                'finalPrice' => [
                    'amount' => $finalPrice,
                ],
            ],
            'priceType' => $selection->getSelectionPriceType(),
            'tierPrice' => $this->getTierPrices($product, $selection),
            'name' => $selection->getName(),
            'sku' => $selection->getSku(),
            'productUrl' => $selection->getProductUrl(), // added the product url here
            'canApplyMsrp' => false,
        ];
```

And pass this to `product-summary.js`. You can add a mixin to override this JS in your module.

**`vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/web/js/product-summary.js`**

inside the function `_renderOptionRow: function (key, optionIndex)`

add this inside `data` object

```
_productUrl_: this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].productUrl
```

This is how you can make bundle product options clickable and redirect to the product page when its clicked.

Comment: Thanks,your code is working! I've overwritten the files in my theme and works like a charm.

Comment: @Petacchi Glad to know it works like a Charm !